# Best approach in sliding image and appending some room for content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working with a jquery and I have this image that is the main problem. I googled it but came up with nothing. Here is my content for example.

[image]

And when the `guy(in the picture above)` is being click I want it to slide to the left side and will looked like this. Please see image below.

[image]

So what I'm thinking is 
**1.** using `addClass` and `removeClass` using jquery or
**2.** just use jquery `.slide` or `toggle` function?

If there's a solution  as such how could it be done? Since I only know is using `addClass` tho. And also what I'm planning is when the image **exceeds** `800px` then the `girl(in the image)` will be send to back of the `guy image`.

Comment: You have to use slide.

Comment: @AngularHarsh How can I make it using `.slide` function? I tried googling it but using `.slide` makes the container `hide` or `show`?  Is there any sample for that animation? Any link will be appreciated!

Comment: Yes it will basically hide or show. For sliding you need animation in jquery. Pretty standard stuff. Google it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is create a mask around the guy. The scope of this question is beyond masking. Most methods of masking don't have large browser support at this moment so posting more on this would be disingenuous. But worth googling otherwise you can use the transform property to move the picture to the left. But you won't get the results you are looking for..

But there is the option of masking the picture in Photoshop and saving it as a PNG. And then utilizing the translate CSS method to move the image to left. This is your best option. But the details of either of these methods are out of scope for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Cut this guy from image and put in another div at needed position. Put blue box between those two images and use slide function. You can cut the guy from his head i think.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to have an html structure like this:

```
<div id='container'>  
  <div id='couple'></div>
  <div id='mask'></div>
</div>
```

Initially in your css:

```
#mask {
   display: none;
}
```

And, of course, you have to align horizzontally this two div.

Your jquery will have a behavior like this:

```
$('#couple').on('click', slide);

var slide = function() {
   $target = $('#container');
   $mask = $('#mask');
   $mask.fadeIn();
   $target.animate({
    left: "+=50"
   }, 500, function() {
     /* callback on end*/
   });
}
```

For complete documentation of **[animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)** check api jquery.